# C# compound assignment operator ^=

Tags: c#

What does this operator ^= mean in c#?

Comment: As all the other answers said, its an `XOR` operator. A good explanation of that is [here](http://blog.typps.com/2007/10/bitwise-operators-in-c-or-xor-and-not.html)

Comment: Why not ask [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5E=)? Or any reference book, for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means bitwise XOR the value of the LHS expression with the value of the RHS expression, and assign it back to the LHS expression.

So for example:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 3;

x ^= y; // x = 10 ^ 3, i.e. 9
```

The LHS expression is only evaluated once, so if you have:

```
array[GetIndex()] ^= 10;
```

that would only call `GetIndex` once. But please don't do that, 'cos it's nasty :)

See also the [relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx).

You may also find [Eric Lippert's recent April Fool's Day blog post on compound assignment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/compound-assignment-part-two) amusing - and [part one of the series, which was rather more serious, may prove enlightening](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/compound-assignment-part-one).

Answer (score 2):

this:

```
x ^= y;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
x = x ^ y;
```

In words, set x to the value of x exclusive or'ed with y.

Answer (score 1):

The exclusive-OR assignment operator.

An expression of the form

```
 x ^= y
```

is evaluated as

```
 x = x ^ y
```

except that x is only evaluated once. The ^ operator performs a bitwise exclusive-OR operation on integral operands and logical exclusive-OR on bool operands.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is the "exclusive or assignment" operator.  Details are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

XOR. `a ^= b` is the same as `a = a ^ b`, where a and b are integer types of some sort.